# CefSharp 79.1.360 (Winform): How to reactivate popup in LifeSpanHandler

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I have been able to handle the popup window when clicking a link in the main Cefsharp browser using the LifSpanHandler interface.  However, if a different pop-up link is clicked, none of the events like OnBeforePopup or OnAfterCreated are fired in the LifSpanHandler interface.  It works if I close the popup window.  Are there an event that I can use to detect when the new link is loaded into the popup window when the popup window is already there?  I put a break point in either events but neither is firing if the popup window is there.

My ultimate goal is to load a different window icon to the pop-up window depending on the link being clicked.

This is my LifeSpanHandler interface class:

```
using CefSharp;
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows;

namespace LifeSpanHandlerExample
{
    internal class LifeSpanHandler : ILifeSpanHandler
    {

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern bool SetWindowText(IntPtr hwnd, String lpString);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int message, int wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr SetFocus(IntPtr hWnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

    private const int WM_SETICON = 0x80;
    private const int ICON_SMALL = 0;
    private const int ICON_BIG = 1;

    public bool DoClose(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser)
    {
        //
        return false; 
    }

    public void OnAfterCreated(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser)
    {
        if (!browser.IsDisposed && browser.IsPopup)
        {
            System.IntPtr _handle = browser.GetHost().GetWindowHandle();
            Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(Inc3DAppHelper.Properties.Resources.Incodema3D);
            Icon icon = Icon.FromHandle(bm.GetHicon());
            SendMessage(_handle, WM_SETICON, ICON_BIG, icon.Handle);
        }
    }

    public void OnBeforeClose(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser)
    {
        //
    }

    public bool OnBeforePopup(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, string targetUrl, string targetFrameName, WindowOpenDisposition targetDisposition, bool userGesture, IPopupFeatures popupFeatures, IWindowInfo windowInfo, IBrowserSettings browserSettings, ref bool noJavascriptAccess, out IWebBrowser newBrowser)
    {
        //Default Behavior
        newBrowser = null;

        return false;  //return true to cancel popup creation
    }


}
```

}

Comment: The behaviour you are seeing is expected if the popup is already open. You can implement other interfaces like http://cefsharp.github.io/api/79.1.x/html/T_CefSharp_ILoadHandler.htm or http://cefsharp.github.io/api/79.1.x/html/T_CefSharp_IDisplayHandler.htm The methods of these will be called for the main browser and the popup, if you are only interested in popups then use http://cefsharp.github.io/api/79.1.x/html/P_CefSharp_IBrowser_IsPopup.htm to filter out the main browser

Comment: Excellent.  Thank you for pointing to the right direction.  I'll give the ILoadHandler a try with the Popup filtering.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to amaitland, I was able to implement the ILoadHandler as he suggested.  This is pretty cool since it also solves the popup window not being able to popup to the front if it's already opened.  I can also now change the icon by know the URL link but I'll work on that later.  For other people trying to solve the same problem, here's the code for the LoadHandler interface class to bring the popup window up to the front.

```
using CefSharp;
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows;

namespace CefSharpExample
{
    internal class LoadHandler : ILoadHandler
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr SetFocus(IntPtr hWnd);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

        public void OnFrameLoadEnd(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, FrameLoadEndEventArgs frameLoadEndArgs)
        {
          //
        }

        public void OnFrameLoadStart(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, FrameLoadStartEventArgs frameLoadStartArgs)
        {
        //
        }

        public void OnLoadError(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, LoadErrorEventArgs loadErrorArgs)
        {
             //
        }

        public void OnLoadingStateChange(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, LoadingStateChangedEventArgs loadingStateChangedArgs)
        {
             if (loadingStateChangedArgs.Browser.IsPopup)
             {
                System.IntPtr _handle = loadingStateChangedArgs.Browser.GetHost().GetWindowHandle();
                 {
                     SetFocus(_handle);
                     SetForegroundWindow(_handle);
                 }
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably only want to setfocus when http://cefsharp.github.io/api/79.1.x/html/P_CefSharp_LoadingStateChangedEventArgs_IsLoading.htm is true or when it's false depending on your requirements. As it stands you'll be setting focus when the page starts loading then again when it's finished.